# How to do a Validation Using Jquery- Using .netcore

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have an academy platform where the section assessment test is a combination of the following type of questions

1. Single Answer ( radio button)
2. Multiple choice ( checkbox)
3. True or false ( radio button)
4. reorder ( where I have listed the answers as a drop-down)

I have initialized the following on to the final assessment view:

We are trying to achieve that a user should be able to answer the question as well as at the same time the answer should be validated/checked.

If the user has the right answer to the question then they can move to the next section.

Currently, we are trying to achieve the above-said goal by using the below jquery

```
var checkedValues = [];
 $('.next').click(function() {
    var $form = $(this).parent().parent();
    var $checked =     $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=radio]:checked')
    var isChecked = $checked.length > 0;
    if(!isChecked){
      alert('Please Choose an option.');
      return;
    }
    checkedValues.push($checked.val());
    console.log($checked.val());
    $form.hide().next().show(); //hide parent and show next
  });

  $('.back').click(function() {
    console.log('back');
    $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show(); //hide parent and show previous
  });
```

However, we are unable to achieve to move the user to the next section and also validate the answer. can anyone please help?

PS I have already tried the fieldset method but it does not work in terms of validation and moving to sections. Sections are dynamic. We have to make sure that a user should answer the section assessment before moving to the next section.

Comment: Can you share the html codes?